# How to Manage Changing of Views?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript

Should I use a router to manage changing of views? Currently, I'm using a 'parent' view to handle 'child' view management.

I have multiple 'child' views within a single parent. Child views/pages are changed by clicking links, which also modifies the URL. The changing of the displayed view is handled by the parent view -- NOT a router. The router in question has nothing of value coded, I created the 'dummy' router so I could use `Backbone.history`

Comment: So, here's a question:  If the url is changed, could somebody copy/paste that url into another browser window and get essentially into the same state that you were when you click/navigated to that url?

Comment: @JayC: Yes, if the url is changed somebody could copy/paste that url into another browser window and get essentially the same state that the original browser is in when you click/navigated to that url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you searching for some sort of validation that this is a proper way to construct your application.  From the limited information you've given, it's hard to say, and even if you did provide some code, your question might not be definitively answerable, either.

So, let me just put it this way.  I don't think there is any flaw in creating Backbone.js views that are composed of other views.  I *do* think there's something wrong if you're putting everything related to view changing in the router--unless you're giving some sort of high level description there--like passing in views the parent view should show/attach events to/something else.

Another point.  How are the child views related?  Might some of them have a common (high-level) interface?  Or does your parent view wrap disparate things, like a search form and some grids and labels? Or both? Is there some chance that this parent view might be useful on another page, or is it just going to manage this particular pages views, etc.  All this matters.

I suppose there might even a reason to question as to whether or not your parent view should strictly extend from `Backbone.View` or should have some other sort of "base" class.  But if it works and has some reasonable connection to being a "view" I wouldn't bother asking that question.  As Jeff Attwood has said, "meta is murder".  At some point these kinds of discussions become impractical, and *when there are still important issues to be fixed or implemented*, it's best to leave reasonable solutions be.

My thinking is if you are using the router to control and delegate things to the parent view, and let the parent view do it's things with it's child views, you probably fine.

You might want to consider passing in the child views through parent view's constructor in the router, though.  It's often better, but not always better, to have a separate thing determine the composition of an object than to let the object create it's composition itself.  But always go for transparency as well.  Sometimes the freedom you get with dependency injection isn't worth the obtuseness of abstraction your code; especially if you're not quite sure what you're doing. Figure out what you're doing, then consider the abstractions you may not have thought of.

If you want to know if you are doing things consistent with the community's ways of doing certain things, you probably ought to go to the [backbone.js Google discussion group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/backbonejs) and review or ask questions the questions there as well.

Comment: You're right I was looking for either validation or correction of my approach. The Rails router, rather than the Backbone router, delegates to the 'parent' view, which then manages all 'child' view state and changes. The Backbone router is essentially empty; it exists so I can use `Backbone.history`. I'm going to take your advice and re-ask this question the Backbone Google discussion group. Thanks.